# Utilizing STUFF within Cross Apply - syntax

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Right now the following is working and producing mostly desired results except its putting a trailing comma after the comma separated list..  I understand I should use STUFF to rid the trailing comma but I can't seem to get the syntax right on where to insert the STUFF and the FOR XML PATH('')) , 1, 2, '')

```
SELECT DISTINCT keyid, [DerivedColumn] FROM table A
CROSS APPLY (SELECT A.type + ',' FROM table B WHERE A.keyid=B.keyid 
ORDER BY A.typenum FOR XML PATH('')) AS C (DerivedColumn)
```

Thx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LEFT` plus `LEN` function to trim the *trailing comma* it is way simpler than `STUFF`

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT keyid, 
                LEFT([derivedcolumn], Len(derivedcolumn) - 1) AS DerivedColumn 
FROM   table A 
       CROSS apply (SELECT A.type + ',' 
                    FROM   table B 
                    WHERE  A.keyid = B.keyid 
                    ORDER  BY A.typenum 
                    FOR xml path('')) AS C (derivedcolumn)
```